# Getting linker error in visual solution c++

Tags: c++, linker-errors

one project has two files Hello.h and Hello .cpp

**Hello.h**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
class Hello{
    void print ();
}
```

**Hello.cpp**

```
#include <Hello.h>
    void Hello:: print (){
    std::cout << "hello";
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Hello.h"
int main(){
    Hello hl;
    hl.print();
}
```

Getting undefined reference to print. In visual studio how to set the object files that are to be linked ?

Comment: ya while pasting the code I missed ; in the code which I am compiling , syntactically is correct but has linking issues.

Comment: By default, a class will make it's members as private. So, if you want to access the function `print()`, you should specify it as a public member function of the class. But even then, you should be getting an error like this : **error: ‘void Hello::print()’ is private within this context**. Can you post the exact error that you get ?

Answer (score 0):

I see two things here( the undefined reference you face is due to the 1st point ) :

1. In `Hello.cpp`, you have included the header as `#include <Hello.h>` instead of `#include "Hello.h"`. The latter is what we should do when we want include user created header files unless you have added your header file to list of system headers( I assume you have not done that ). See [include syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html) for more.
2. By default, a class will make it's members as private. So, if you want to access the function `print()`, you should specify it as a public member function of the class. This would throw **error: ‘void Hello::print()’ is private within this context**, but you are not getting this due to the aforementioned point.